# Angular 5, How to place a lock for http calls

Tags: angular, asynchronous, synchronization, angular-httpclient

I have implementation of web socket client. It listens to server 1 for responses. As soon as the client receives the response from the server 1. It connects to the another server 2 via http, to get the objects. I am looking a synchronous calls to the server 2. Can someone please point me, how this can be achieved?

Sample code: This is where the client listens to the server 1.

```
this.chatSubscription = this.stompClient.subscribe("/chat/" + id, (message) => {
  console.log(message.body);
  this.store.dispatch(new NotificationActions.TryNotificationsList({
    url: this.utilService.host + 'message'
  }));
});
```

Effects code: This is where client connects to server 2 via http to get the objects. Here is where I am trying to put a lock so that there will be only one request set to the server 2.

```
@Effect({
  dispatch: false
})
actionTryNotificationsList = this.actions$
  .ofType(NotificationActions.TRY_NOTIFICATIONS_LIST)
  .switchMap((actions: NotificationActions.TryNotificationsList) => {
      const data = actions.payload;
      return this.requestsService.getRequest(data.url)
        .pipe(catchError(this.requestsService.handleError < any > ('Unable to connect to server')))
        .map((response: any) => {

            if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
              if (response) {
                this.displayNotificationService.notificationsList$.next(notificationsList);
              }
          }
         }
```

code for getRequest function:

```
                getRequest(url: string) {
                  const tkn = this.cookieService.get("token");
                  const httpOptions = {
                    observe: 'body',
                    responseType: 'json',
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({
                      'token': tkn,
                      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                    })
                  };
                  const req = new HttpRequest("GET", url, httpOptions);
                  return this.httpClient.request(req);
                }
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Please point me how I can implement the lock. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more field to the state, like `serverCalled: boolean`, which you will change to true in the first time from this effect(after getting data from server 2). And above the call, you can always check if you have requested this data during this 'session', from your store. Or even in your sample code you could subscribe to changes of store with selector, so even before dispatching this action, you can get the actual value of that variable and pass one more field in payload, like `shouldLoadData: true | false` so in effect you will only check for it and will or won't make that call to the service. Hope it helps, at least that's how I see it for now.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to ignore the new request to server 2 if the process is already in progress. We don't want to skip/reject any requests to server 2. Do you have any sample reference for locking the http request calls please?